# Strange behaviour of NSScanner on simple whitespace removal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsscanner

I'm trying to replace all multiple whitespace in some text with a single space. This should be a very simple task, however for some reason it's returning a different result than expected. I've read the docs on the NSScanner and it seems like it's not working properly!

```
NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:@"This    is   a test of NSScanner   !"];
NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSString *temp;
NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {

    // Scan upto and stop before any whitespace
    [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:whitespace intoString:&temp];

    // Add all non whotespace characters to string
    [result appendString:temp];

    // Scan past all whitespace and replace with a single space
    if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:whitespace intoString:NULL]) {
        [result appendString:@" "];
    }

}
```

But for some reason the result is `@"ThisisatestofNSScanner!"` instead of `@"This is a test of NSScanner !"`.

If you read through the comments and what each line should achieve it seems simple enough!? `scanUpToCharactersFromSet` should stop the scanner just as it encounters whitespace. `scanCharactersFromSet` should then progress the scanner past the whitespace up to the non-whitespace characters. And then the loop continues to the end.

What am I missing or not understanding?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out! By default the NSScanner skips whitespace!

Turns out you just have to set `charactersToBeSkipped` to `nil`:

```
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't guarantee that `nil` will work there; it's safer to use an empty NSCharacterSet object instead. One way to create one would be `[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithRange:(NSRange){ ' ', 0 }]`.

Comment: Looks like `nil` is fine now according to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/setCharactersToBeSkipped:) .  `skipSet - The characters to ignore when scanning for a value representation. Pass nil to not ignore any characters.`

Comment: Omg thanks, I spent about 2 hours banging my head to the keyboard to see why it's ignoring my spaces