# Strip out HTML Tags etc from NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove HTML Tags from an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

I would like to know the best method for stripping out all HTML/Javascript etc tags out of an NSString.

The current solution I am using leaves comments and other tags in, what would be the best way to remove them?

I know OF solutions e.g. LibXML, but I would like some examples to work with.

Current solution:

```
- (NSString *)flattenHTML:(NSString *)html trimWhiteSpace:(BOOL)trim {

    NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *text = nil;

    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

    while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

        // find start of tag
        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL] ;                 
        // find end of tag         
        [theScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text] ;

        // replace the found tag with a space
        //(you can filter multi-spaces out later if you wish)
        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:
                [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text]
                                               withString:@""];
    }

    // trim off whitespace
    return trim ? [html stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] : html;  
}
```

Comment: @x3ro so vote to close it as a duplicate

Comment: @Mark He did, that comment is automatically added (for the benefit of the poster) when a person votes to close.

Comment: Hmm the close count was still zero when I saw it

Comment: @Mark: I would've, but I can't see the "Close" link :)

Answer (score 17):

Try this method to remove HTML tags from a String:

```
- (NSString *)stripTags:(NSString *)str
{
    NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[str length]];

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
    scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = NULL;
    NSString *tempText = nil;

    while (![scanner isAtEnd])
    {
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:&tempText];

        if (tempText != nil)
            [html appendString:tempText];

        [scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:NULL];

        if (![scanner isAtEnd])
            [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation] + 1];

        tempText = nil;
    }

    return html;
}
```

Comment: I added `scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = NULL` to code above to avoid word glueing as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828737/strange-behaviour-of-nsscanner-on-simple-whitespace-removal

Comment: Aside from many contrived cases, the more basic case of "my string with a < and some other stuff" fails with this code.

Comment: The code correctly only in some cases. E.g. `Then x < 12 then y > 10` we will receive `Then x  10`

Comment: I was looking for a method that would strip ```<source srcset>``` tags from a HTML string, this works perfectly, thanks!