# Objective-C: strip HTML tags from strings

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove HTML Tags from an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)
>   [Strip out HTML Tags etc from NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170531/strip-out-html-tags-etc-from-nsstring)

I'm getting some strings returned in JSON dictionaries that look like this:

```
"<p>There are <span class=\"top-color-red\">7</span> magical worlds ahead!</p>"
```

In Objective-C and the Foundation framework, is there a way to strip all of the tags and HTML cruft to just display the string as it would be rendered?

```
There are 7 magical worlds ahead!
```

If this requires use of an external library, can you post a code snippet with my string as an example?

Thank you!

Comment: Closing question, thanks. Interestingly, when I typed the question title, these answers did not appear in the results of "similar questions". When I posted the question, the Related links in the side bar had links to duplicates. Sort of a what-the-hell moment

Comment: Here is the mandatory link for attempting/wanting/considering parsing html with regex: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). And mergesort, nice adding a link to a relevant question that is also closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

If the strings can be trusted to be well-formed, the simplest option is probably to use `NSXMLParser`; implementing the delegate method `-parser:foundCharacters:`, using an accumulator to gather the textual content of the document fragment.

If you can't trust them to be well-formed XML, but *can* trust them to be valid HTML; you can use `NSAttributedString` and its `-initWithHTML:documentAttributes:` method, and extract the text from the string after it has been created.

If you can't trust it to be valid HTML; run away.

Very, very fast.

Comment: But what do you do in the case that it's not?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: Then you fix whatever is emitting the HTML, so that you can trust it to be well-formed XML.

Comment: What if it's someone else's site that your parsing? btw, just playing devils advocate. I tried parsing someone else's HTML with an NSXMLParser not too long ago and couldn't get it to work. I ended up writing my own special case parser instead.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: If it's someone else's site, you either don't do it, if you don't have the appropriate permissions, or ask them to fix their API if they do, maybe even have them give you an actual XML API.