# iOS - Loading text from website has HTML tags in text view. Need to remove them

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextview

In my app, I have a table view with a detail view. The detail view loads blog posts from [HERE](http://www.pointzeroradio.com/4/feed) and the detail view will display the text from that post. I almost have it working but I still need to figure out how I can fix the text (example below). Here is the code I have to pull the text from the website in the detail view:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
                                          //self.url is from the table view where the link to the website is
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [self.url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL]; 
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(LoadText) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)webViewDidLoadText {

    NSString *textForBlog = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('paragraph')[0].innerHTML;"];

    self.textView.text = textForBlog;

}
```

[image]

Comment: None of the methods there worked for me.

Comment: This method seems to work just fine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6171866/308315

Comment: Could you give an example on how I should go about using it? I an a little stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code as an example, this is how you'd implement it:

```
-(void)webViewDidLoadText {

    NSString *textForBlog = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('paragraph')[0].innerHTML;"];

    // Add this step for stripping the HTML from the text you received
    NSString *strippedTextForBlog = [self stringByStrippingHTMLFromString:textForBlog];

    self.textView.text = strippedTextForBlog;

}

// Taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170531/strip-out-html-tags-etc-from-nsstring/6171866#6171866
- (NSString *)stringByStrippingHTMLFromString:(NSString *)str
{
    NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[str length]];

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
    scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = NULL;
    NSString *tempText = nil;

    while (![scanner isAtEnd])
    {
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:&tempText];

        if (tempText != nil)
            [html appendString:tempText];

        [scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:NULL];

        if (![scanner isAtEnd])
            [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation] + 1];

        tempText = nil;
    }

    return html;
}
```

Comment: @KyleGreenlaw You're welcome, good luck w/ the apps Kyle

Comment: Is there any way I could scan for a word and not include it in the displayed text using stringByStrippingHTMLFromString?

Comment: @KyleGreenlaw Use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` on the string and replace it with `@""`