# iOS NSString Flatten Html While Keeping The Paragraph Tags

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have a NSString containing some html that i am retrieving from a web service. What i need to do is to remove html links from it so i can display it as a plain text.

I have seen a few questions that are related to flattening html [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606134/iphone-xcode-how-to-convert-nsstring-html-markup-to-plain-text-nsstring), [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170531/strip-out-html-tags-etc-from-nsstring).

Unfortunately, what all these methods have in common is that they strip all the html from it including the paragraph tags and all the text ends up showing as a single unit.

What i want is to have a method that only strips the html links from it and keep the paragraph tags. How can i achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem without having to make a lot of changes. I have taken the method flattenHtml from [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606134/iphone-xcode-how-to-convert-nsstring-html-markup-to-plain-text-nsstring) and did one modification to keep the paragraph tags. Instead of using only "<", i used "

```
- (NSString *)flattenHTML:(NSString *)html {

    NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *text = nil;
    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

    while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<a" intoString:NULL] ; 

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text] ;

        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text] withString:@""];
    }
    //
    html = [html stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    return html;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

There is another way, that works in iOS 7 and later:

```
NSAttributedString* attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                      options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                                NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                                           documentAttributes:nil
                                                                        error:nil];
NSString* plainText = [attributedText string];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use GTMNSString-HTML. Just download from [here](https://github.com/siriusdely/GTMNSString-HTML)

Import it to your project. Now you use the below method for flatten HTML

```
- (NSString *)stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText
```

If you want keep the paragraph tag modify **dontReplaceTagWithSpace** inside the above method

```
dontReplaceTagWithSpace = ([tagName isEqualToString:@"p"] || OTHER TAG CHECKINGS....);
```